# Put HashMap<String,String> into ListVIew with section headers

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

I have a HashMap of this data:

```
{Chefs Choice=Vegetable Samosa with Yogurt Sauce},
{Chefs Choice=Tomato Red Pepper Chutney}, 
{Cold Cereal=Miscellaneous/Peripherals}, {Dessert=Cheesecake Slice}, 
{Dessert=Banana Cream Pie with Caramel Topping}
```

And now I want to put this data into a ListView that will look like this.

[image]

So that the key,s are all section headers and then the values of each key goes in that section header. I thinking of using a base adapter but not quite sure how to get it right. Or if there is a better way for me to organize my data. I am also open to that.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Here is how I add data:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = xmlData.getName();
            HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                        currentDay = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("meal")) {
                        currentMeal = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("counter") && currentDay.equalsIgnoreCase(day) && currentMeal.equalsIgnoreCase(meal)) {
                        mealArray.add(xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        counter = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }

                    break;
                case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
                    if (currentDay.equalsIgnoreCase(day) && currentMeal.equalsIgnoreCase(meal)) {
                        if (xmlData.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                            Log.i(TAG, blogPost + "");
                            blogPost.put(counter, xmlData.getText());
                            blogPosts.add(blogPost);
                        }

                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    recordsFound++;
                    break;
            }
            eventType = xmlData.next();
        }
```

Comment: You could use just about any adapter with this, just need to manage things in getView().

Comment: i don't understand your data structure. HashMap cannot have multiple entries for the same key. or is it a list of maps?

Comment: @njzk2 hmm well when I added the data in it went in...? What would the best way to organize my data to achieve this listview

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. post the code you use for setting this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the main header tag as arraylist.
Data structure will be like this:

Main tag of hashmap will be coming from arraylist and its value will be list of hashmap again...

Like    tag   'chef choice': vegatable ssamosa and tomato red

```js
// list contain your top header.....
List<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
//list to store complete data structure. 
List<HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>>> list =new ArrayList<HashMap<String,List<HashMap<String,String>>>>();


// setting the data structure
HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> hash=new HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String,String>>>();
  List<HashMap<String, String>> hash1=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
  HashMap<String, String> hash2=new HashMap<String, String>();
  hash2.put("tag", "vegetable");
  hash1.add(hash2);
    // getting tag from tag list......
  hash.put(list.get(i).toString(), hash1);
  list.add(hash);
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more, maybe add some sample code?